# how to make login with two different tables depending if the user enters an email or a nickname?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working with Laravel for first time, I am trying to make a login depending either the user enters an email or a nickname within the same input. Database has among others 2 tables, one `Users` which has an email field, and another one `Profile` which has an nick field and which id is a foreign key from `Users`, in the front ed the inputs are as they come with the email input only being changed from type email to type text so the user can enter either an email or a nickname, then I have tried different ways around, last thing I tried is  including a provider in the auth.php like this:

```
   'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'profiles' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'profiles',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

then I have tried to override the attemptLogin within the LoginController like this:

```
    public function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {

        if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            $details = Auth::guard('web')->user();
            $user = $details['original'];
            return $user;
        } else {
            return 'auth with email failed';
        }

        if (Auth::guard('profiles')->attempt(['nick' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            $details = Auth::guard('profiles')->user();
            $user = $details['original'];
            return $user;
        } else {
            return 'auth with nick failed';
        }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated as I am new to Laravel and I am kinda lost

Comment: Why don't you just have one table of users and have a "nickname" or "profile_name" column in there?

Comment: And you could check auth against both columns

Comment: that is not a posiblity as the database is in production already....

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this before, but here are a few hints:

Take a look at your `config/auth.php` file, more specifically the `User Providers` section. There you can change the model that represents the user depending on the provider.

You may also need to update which field you use for identifying the user, for that check the trait `\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`, more specifically the method `\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers::username`. Usually we can overwrite it in the controller, but you might want to change that on a middleware if possible.

Comment: Upvoted. Yes, by default, Laravel uses the `email` field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a `username` method on `LoginController`:

Comment: but what if I want to use the email or the nickname depending on what the user enter in the input?

Comment: I guess you could check that in a middleware and then decide which provider to use.